# How to use T4 to generate two files at the same time from one template?

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, t4, webservice-client

I am having a case in which I need to generate two CSharp code files with pretty the same code but different namespace of the input and output types of the methods. In fact each file is for a specific country and the types come from country specific WSDL's.

I am writing some wrappers around the services and the logic is exactly the same but the types automatically generated from WSDL's are different. How could I reduce the coding effort and write the logic at one place and get it generated for two different sets of types?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

or you could use the [T4 Toolbox](http://olegsych.com/T4Toolbox/) ([Old CodePlex project](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/), [New GitHub project](https://github.com/olegsych/T4Toolbox)) and use the helpers to generate multiple files.

The author, Oleg Sych, has [a documentary blog post](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creating-complex-code-generators/) ([Archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20160502195100/http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creating-complex-code-generators/))

Or if you don't want this dependency just for this functionality, [you can use the T4 file MultiOutput.tt](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/) ([Archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20160501025241/http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/))

Comment: The link for the T4 MultiOutput.tt file is dead. Is there another link to this out there?

Comment: Try this alternate link instead: https://damieng.com/blog/2009/01/22/multiple-outputs-from-t4-made-easy